# HTML5 audio recording not woorking in Google Nexus

Tags: android, html, audio, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I want to use HTML5 getusermedia to record audio, play back and save to server. I am trying with Google Nexus (Android 4+) and Google Chrome 29. Is it possible? When I try the codes I got from net, it asks permission to record using microphone and using the phone, I save a wav file. But no sound on playing this. The same site works from chromium browser in my PC. Am I doing anything wrong? or is it that audio recording is not actually working as it claims?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We now have Web Audio input working in Chrome for Android Beta (31.0.1650.11).

Comment: When do you expect to have mic inputs on android working? I'm not getting any errors, just 0's in the stream buffer. Thanks for the progress so far!

Comment: Working now!  revising answer.

Comment: @cwilso No such luck in the non-beta build version 31.0.1650.59.  Any idea when this will hit the stable builds?

Comment: Brad, what device are you using?  My Nexus 5 on 31.0.1650.59 (stable) works.